# how to import a css file from an npm module - webcomponent

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-3.x, lit-element

I'm trying to use MDC Components for material design components on my application. I have a custom element in Polymer (LitElement):

```
_render(props) {
        return html`
            ${SharedStyles}
            <style>
                .js-panel {
                    display: none;
                }
                .js-panel.is-active {
                    display: block;
                }
            </style>

            <div class="mdc-toolbar">
                <div class="mdc-toolbar__row">
                    <div class="mdc-toolbar__section mdc-toolbar__section--align-start">
                        <nav id="tab1" class="mdc-tab-bar mdc-tab-bar--indicator-accent  js-tabs" role="tablist">
                            <a role="tab" aria-controls="panel-1" class="mdc-tab mdc-tab--active">Item One</a>
                            <a role="tab" aria-controls="panel-2" class="mdc-tab">Item Two</a>
                            <span class="mdc-tab-bar__indicator"></span>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <section>
                <div class="js-panels" for='tab1'>
                    <p class="js-panel is-active" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="false">Item One</p>
                    <p class="js-panel" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true">Item Two</p>
                </div>
            </section>
        `
    }
```

I have imported from @material/tabs all the classes needs to create the component, and it actually works perfectly fine but the styles doesn't apply:
[image: npm module]

In the `dist` folder we have the css file `mdc.tabs.css` that has all the css for the component. I did the test copying all the file content into the style tag and it applies all the styles correctly, but I think it should be a better way to do that... My question is how can I import the css file into my webcomponent?

Comment: I already create a component that export a custom element that contain the style copied and also reference like the `${SharedStyles}` and it works but I'm still wonder if there is any way to reference that, or probably the actual component can export that in their custom elements

Comment: Have you tried using material design's web components rather than the normal repo? https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web-components

Comment: Thanks @AlanDávalos but the problem is that Tabs is not ready yet to be used in production, actually I did checked how they are importing css and they are doing exactly the same that I commented in my first comment

Comment: Indeed that is the recommended way. Also `SharedStyles` doesn't have to be necessarily an entire lit-element, you should be able to make a `sharedStyles` variable: `const sharedStyles = html\`<style> ... </style>\``, and include it in tour template: `return html\`${sharedStyles} ... \``

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the traditional approach when you `render()` your html:

`<link href="./mdc.tabs.css" rel="stylesheet">`