# How to import Material Design Components into Progressive Web App Starter Kit?

Tags: material-design, progressive-web-apps, mdc-components, pwa-starter-kit

I want to use [Material Design Component: Lists](https://material.io/develop/web/components/lists/) into my [Progressive Web App Starter Kit](https://github.com/Polymer/pwa-starter-kit).

So...

```
npm install @material/list
```

Now what?

All I can think to do is

```
import { MDCList } from '@material/list/dist/mdc.list.css'
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/@material/list/dist/mdc.list.css"/>
```

Both produce errors. What should I do?

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: Check on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50518495/how-to-import-a-css-file-from-an-npm-module-webcomponent

Answer (score 0):

You can download the materialize css and js files at keep it at the root level of the project folder

then in the app.js (your entry point file)

```
 html`
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/materialize.min.css" />
      <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<div> Your content here..</div>
`
```

give the path according to the folder you have created